# Google Chrome Extension - prevent cookie on jquery ajax request or Use a chome.extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a great working chrome extension now.

It basically loops over a list of HTML of a web auction site, if a user has not paid for to have the image shown in the main list. A default image is shown.

- My plugin use a jQuery Ajax request to load the auction page and find the main image to display as a thumbnail for any missing images. WORKS GREAT.
- The plugin finds the correct image url and update the HTML Dom to the new image and sets a new width.

The issue is, that the auction site tracks all pages views and saves it to a "recently viewed" section of the site "users can see any auctions they have clicked on"

ISSUE
- My plugin uses ajax and the cookies are sent via the jQuery ajax request. I am pretty sure I cannot modify the cookies in this request so the auction site tracks the request and for any listing that has a missing image this listing is now shown in my "recently viewed" even though I have not actually navigated to it.

1. Can I remove cookies for ajax request (I dont think I can)
2. Can chrome remove the cookie (only for the ajax requests)
3. Could I get chrome to make the request (eg curl, with no cookie?)

Just for the curious.
Here is a page with missing images on this auction site

http://www.trademe.co.nz/Browse/SearchResults.aspx?searchType=all&searchString=toaster&type=Search&generalSearch_keypresses=9&generalSearch_suggested=0

Thanks for any input, John.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`webRequest`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/webRequest.html) API to intercept and modify requests (including blanking headers). It cannot be used to modify requests which are created within the context of a Chrome extension though. If you want to use this API for cookie-blanking purposes, you have to load the page in a non-extension context. Either by [creating a new tab](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-create), or use an off-screen tab (using the [experimental offscreenTabs API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/experimental.offscreenTabs.html).

Another option is to use the [`chrome.cookie`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/cookies.html) API, and bind a `onChanged` event. Then, you can intercept cookie modifications, and revert the changes using [`chrome.cookies.set`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/cookies.html#method-set).

The last option is to create a new window+tab in Incognito mode. This method is not reliable, and should not be used:

- The user can disallow access to the Incognito mode
- The user could have navigated to the page in incognito mode, causing cookie fields to be populated.
- It's disruptive: A new window is created.

Comment: Thanks heaps rob for that information. There are some ideas that I can try there to see if that can get around my problem. Cheers, John.

Comment: FYI, it's been six years and offscreen tabs never became a thing.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably this AJAX interaction is being run from a content script? Could you run it from the background page instead and pass the data to the content script? I **belive** the background page operates in a different context and shouldn't send the normal cookies.

Comment: Cookies are tied to a domain, not to the requestor.

Comment: Yes but if the background page operates in a different context then the site shouldn't tie that activity to the user browsing the site and so it won't show up in the history. Akin to having the site open in a separate incognito tab.

Comment: "Cookies are tied to a domain" = Existing cookies are send regardless of the page which is initiating the request. Background pages still send cookies.