# Why is my XMLHttpRequest getting a robots.txt response

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I'm writing a personal Chrome extension (Note: these can make cross-origin requests. See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr).

I'm trying to use XMLHttpRequest to access a certain website, then extract data from it using javascript. My problem is that this website often returns its "robots" page to me instead of the HTML. Of course, when I visit this website in my browser, it works fine. Also, if I visit the website with my browser THEN make the XHR request, it also works fine.

I thought the problem might be that my request headers were not correct. I then modified my request headers so that they were identical to my browser ones (using chrome.webRequest). Unfortunately, this did not work either. One thing I noticed is that my browser has some cookies in its request headers, which I do not know how to replicate (see below).

Therefore, my question is: how can I solve or debug this problem? Is there a way to find out WHY the site is delivering its "robots" page to me? If I view its robots.txt file, I am not breaking any obvious rules. I am pretty new to javascript and web programming, so sorry if this is a basic question.

---

Here is an example of my browser request headers:

> GET /XXX/XXX HTTP/1.1
>
> Host: www.example.com
>
> Connection: keep-alive
>
> Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
>
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98
>   Safari/537.36
>
> Accept:
>   text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
>
> Referer: https://www.example.com/XXX
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
>
> Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
>
> Cookie: D_IID=XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX; D_UID=XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX;
>   D_ZID=XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX; D_ZUID=XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX;
>   D_HID=XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX; D_SID=XXX/XXX/XXX

---

### UPDATE

I am also including my "General" headers defined in Chrome:

> Request URL: https://www.example.com/XXX
>
> Request Method: GET
>
> Status Code: 200 OK
>
> Remote Address: XXX
>
> Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

And my response headers:

> Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
>
> Connection: keep-alive
>
> Content-Encoding: gzip
>
> Content-Type: text/html
>
> Date: Wed, 06 Feb 2019 XXX GMT
>
> Edge-Control: no-store, bypass-cache
>
> Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
>
> Server: XXX
>
> Surrogate-Control: no-store, bypass-cache
>
> Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>
> Vary: Accept-Encoding
>
> X-DB: 0
>
> X-DW: 0
>
> X-DZ: XXX

---

### UPDATE 2

After looking at the response HTML, I am not sure what it is. I originally thought it was some kind of ROBOTS response because it says META NAME="ROBOTS", but now I am less sure. Here is the general structure of the HTML.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 XXX GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10; url=example.com" />
<script type="text/javascript">
// SOME JAVASCRIPT
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/example.js" defer></script></head>
<body>
<div id="XXX">&nbsp;</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the case where you don’t get the HTML you expected, what is the HTTP status code of the response?

Comment: @sideshowbarker I added my response headers. I think the HTTP status code you asked for is "200 OK". Let me know if this answers your question, or if there is anything else I can add to it. Thank you.

Comment: @adnbps hi, I am not sure if this is the post you were talking about cause I can't tell if the two problems are the same. In the previous case, it was about chrome hiding the header *Cookie* when you open developer tabs for CORS request. In this case, it seems that you have access to this header. So what you can do now maybe to try with a third party web request tools (Postman for example), and try to isolate which headers make the website send a different response. Then you could try to add that header with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/setRequestHeader

Comment: @semako Thank you. I am having trouble diagnosing the problem. My basic observation is that when I make the request in my browser, my browser includes some cookies in the header. However, when I make the request with XHR, then it does not include cookies in the header. I do not know how to replicate my browser's request (including the cookies) using XHR. Do you have any ideas, or can you point me in the right direction? Thank you.

Comment: @adnbps Here is a test that could help: when you open the page in your browser in incognito mode and inspect the source, does it contains the good HTML? If yes, then there is a way for you to do the same by adding/removing header, no need for cookies (incognito mode don't send them for the first request). However, if the HTML is not valid or if you have to log into the website before, then it means that you can't make it work without asking the user to log into the website first.

Comment: Also as this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/11327842/6571309) state : webRequest can't be used to modify requests which are created within the context of a Chrome extension. So maybe your modification are not taken in accout. Try replacing the website with a fake sever ( you can use https://hookbin.com/ for example), and check if **the headers** are really the same as the browser's.

Comment: Are you receiving a 404 page? (you posted the headers you're receiving but it does not contain the status line i.e. HTTP/1.1 200 OK or HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I take a look at your user agent, you working on a Mac, Apple stuff.

Some background info, Chrome uses the render engine of Safari, because Apple don't allow other engines, Apple policy. In fact Chrome is a just a GUI shield, looks like Chrome however the skeleton is still Safari. That's why when there are problems with Safari, the engine, you are unable to fix the problem. Installing another browser doesn't help when there is a problem with the core. The problem you have is one of them, sad but true. *Let me explain.*

Had similar problems in the past with a (Luondo) webshop embedded (object/iframe) into a website, also cross-policy etc enabled however won't work (only!) on Apple devices. Only Apple users need to visit the domain of the webshop first *before* they can place an order (exactly like you described, cookie problem). It is some kind of stupid security related policy, only exists with use of Safari (or with their required embedded engine).

What I did (however in your case doesn't help I suppose) is to add a message on the page when an Apple device was detected. The message includes a link to the webshop domain that will open in another tabpage. After this, Apple users can place an order. See also this message in Dutch (translation below):

---

[image: apple webshop problem]

---

*Apple users, please note:*

*There is a security issue with Safari, first you have to visit our webshop provider once to be able to place an order.*

*Click on the following link to open the website of our webshop provider and after this you can close it: **[link]Activate order facility onto Apple device[/link]***

*Apologise for the inconvenience.*

---

Not the best translation, however, you get the point I guess. This is (from now, 2019) two years ago and the problem still exists, like you showed us.

### -------------

**Solution:**

Is there a solution anyway, probably not for Apple users (because Apple needs to fix this) however, have you tried it on a Linux/Windows machine with Chrome installed? I bet it will work unless there the are some security restrictions server site that avoids ajax calls, however, I think there are no issues.

**Another approuch:**

**1**. I do not know your skills however you can consider to setup a proxy server to avoid these problems, embed (or better include) the content of the site into your output (cookies included). One warning tho, this can be illegal because you merged content of another site to be something of your own;

**2**. Ask the owner of the site they provide an API to their services.

---

**Personal thoughts about your ajax method:**

If you want to 'merge' html or extracting content (as you call it) of another site (by using javascript) which is not your own, I am in doubt what you tried to do is legal. I think that is also the reason why you don't want to mention the name/domain of the 'service' (example is not the service I suppose). Try to figure out what you want to do is actually legal, if not, this all is a waste of time unless there is an API for it like I explained above.

---

Maybe this all doesn't sound to you like an answer however it will gave you (hopefully) some insight to the actual problem.

Have a nice Saturday, hopes it helps.

Answer (score 2):

> my question is: how can I solve or debug this problem?

To debug try Fiddler, mitmproxy, Wireshark or any http(s) debugging proxy and see how your extension send the XMLHttpRequest headers.

Also try to emulate browser request using [`Postman`](https://www.getpostman.com/downloads/) or run the XMLHttpRequest in Chrome devtool.

And my guess, it is because `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` header.

Comment: I've used Postman before too - it's a good way to try and get to bottom of things. As person mentioned below though I suspect user agent is cause.